Error when uploading files using Streamlit and Langchain
I'mtrying to build a Chatbot with langchain and when I'm trying to use streamlit to interact with it, I have an error as follows:
File "/mount/src/cenace-llm/streamlit_app.py", line 33, in load_pdf
    pdf_loader = PyPDFLoader(file)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_community/document_loaders/pdf.py", line 154, in __init__
    raise ImportError(

So far I've tried different ways to solve the problem, but none of them have worked, in my code I have this:
def load_pdf(file):
    """Load a PDF file and split it into pages."""
    pdf_loader = PyPDFLoader(file)
    page = pdf_loader.load_and_split()
    return page

with st.sidebar:
        st.title("Menú:")
        pdf_docs = st.file_uploader("Cargue los documentos", accept_multiple_files=True)
        pdf_docs = os.path.join("/tmp", pdf_docs) if pdf_docs else None
        if st.button("Submit and Process", key="process_button"):
            with st.spinner("Procesando..."):
                raw_text = load_pdf(pdf_docs)

I know that the problem is that langchain.document_loaders.PyPDFLoader takes in file_path which is a string but I can't seem to find the solution.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

see documentation for file_uploader - it uses io.StringIO() to create file-like object in memory and maybe PyPDFLoader accepts file-like object instead of file path. But it seems st.file_uploader returns object (not path to file) which has function .read() so it can be used as file-like object. In example it use this object with pandas.read_csv(). Maybe you don't need to use os.path.join("/tmp", ...) but directly use pdf_docs in load_pdf()
